# Can I select the architecture of a program from the command line?

Tags: macos, 64-bit

Many of the unix executable binary programs are delivered with more than one architecture:

```
mac:~ mike$ file `which bc`
/usr/bin/bc: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/bc (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/bc (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
```

Is there a way I can select or force a specific architecture to run (mainly for testing to explore the effects that some larger programs or longer running processes have when executing the same workload over different codebases / memory capabilities?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [arch](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/arch/) program to select which architecture of a universal binary to run.

If you wanted to use the 32-bit version of the executable:

```
arch -arch i386 /usr/bin/bc
```

And if you wanted the 64-bit version of the executable:

```
arch -arch x86_64 /usr/bin/bc
```

Note this doesn't work with applications (folders that end in `.app` and have manifests and what not so OS X recognizes them as *applications*), just universal binaries. If you had a app with multiple architectures you'd want to use Launch Services to launch it with a specific architecture.